# Button onclick inside whole clickable div

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have a whole clickable div.
This is my code:

```
<div onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SubClass", "Product", new { id = productClass.HierarchyId })';" class="menu-class">
            <img src="~/Images/ClassImages/@imageName" alt="@productClass.HierarchyShort" />
            <div class="menu-class-text">
                <span>@productClass.HierarchyShort</span>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-class-admin-options">
                <button onclick=" location.href = '@Url.Action("EditClass", "Product")'; ">Edit</button><br/>
                <button onclick=" location.href = '@Url.Action("DeleteClass", "Product")'; ">Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is a div with image of product and group name. And when user hover it, inside the div show 2 buttons Edit and Delete.
The problem is when I click on any button inside Div, its call the div's onclick, not the button's onclick.
PLease any help?
Sorry my english.

Comment: In your CSS code you want to use either !important attribute
Or use z value to choose which one is on top
Id say one will work.

Comment: Please upload your css and i'll have a go

Comment: As matthiasgh said, try adding a higher z-index to the buttons (make sure they are `position:relative;`, too). If not, you can try adding a `event.stopPropagation()` after the button onclick action.

Comment: Expected behavior: the click will trigger the button onclick event, then the div onclick event http://jsfiddle.net/d2Ya5/ If the div onclick runs first, it might be a z-index issue in your CSS

Comment: I try z-index and does not work. In my whole CSS don't use z-index.

Comment: But how to stop the click event of the whole div? event.stopPropogation() is triggering button click followed by div click.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Thanks for all. As say robooneus.
I just put this:

```
<button onclick=" location.href = '@Url.Action("NewClass", "Product")'; event.stopPropagation(); ">Edit</button><br/>
```

And now is working. Thanks all.

Answer (score 18):

For your two buttons, create a new function, and add this code at the beginning :

```
event.cancelBubble = true;
if(event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
```

Then add your own code.

The Html :

```
<div onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SubClass", "Product", new { id = productClass.HierarchyId })';" class="menu-class">
        <img src="~/Images/ClassImages/@imageName" alt="@productClass.HierarchyShort" />
        <div class="menu-class-text">
            <span>@productClass.HierarchyShort</span>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-class-admin-options">
            <button onclick="editClass()">Edit</button><br/>
            <button onclick="deleteClass()"; ">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The Javascript :

```
function editClass() {
   event.cancelBubble = true;
   if(event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();

   location.href = '@Url.Action("EditClass", "Product")';
}

function deleteClass() {
   event.cancelBubble = true;
   if(event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();$

   location.href = '@Url.Action("DeleteClass", "Product")'; 
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Actually both actions(button's and div's) are triggered. You should stop propagation of events using
stopPropagation/cancelBubble. Further reading about bubbling: http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing

Comment: Nice tutorial, best explanation by far. Really helpful, even now in Sept 2019.

Answer (score 6):

As @Sergey mentioned, both actions are being triggered due to the Bubbling propagation of events. The `event.stopPropagation()` will fix it.

Since there is just HTML/JS example, I will also add a React example to fix this onClick inside whole clickable `div`:

```
<div onClick={requestSort()}>
  <DefaultButton onClick={(event) => handleRequestClick(event)} />
</div>
```

And your handle should be something like:

```
const handleRequestClick = (e) => {
  // this will stop the bubbling effect of the parent and child click events
  e.stopPropagation()

 // your actual handle action
 myLogiccForMyButton()

}
```

**Note that the recommendation is to not stop the Bubbling if not necessary:**

Sometimes event.stopPropagation() creates hidden pitfalls that later may become problems, for instance if you were to be adding an `document.addEventListener('click')` to catch all clicks, it won't work where clicks are stopped by `event.stopPropagation()`

Full explanation:

> We create a nested menu. Each submenu handles clicks on its elements and calls stopPropagation so that the outer menu won’t trigger.
> Later we decide to catch clicks on the whole window, to track users’ behavior (where people click). Some analytic systems do that. Usually the code uses document.addEventListener('click'…) to catch all clicks.
> Our analytic won’t work over the area where clicks are stopped by stopPropagation. Sadly, we’ve got a “dead zone”.