# Is it possible to have an <a> trigger before an onclick handler for a parent element?

Tags: html, dom-events

I have a table like this:

```
<table>
  <tr onclick="window.location='foo.html'">
    <td>Data 1</td>
    <td>Data 2</td>
    <td><a href="bar.html">link</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When I try to click the `link` text, I get sent to `foo.html`. I'd like to go to `bar.html` instead. Is there a way to make sure that the `<a>` gets the click event first?

Or do I have to change my `onclick` handler to be on each of the `<td>` elements *except* for the final one containing the link?

Comment: [This might be similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862228/button-onclick-inside-whole-clickable-div) to what you're trying to accomplish

Answer (score 2):

To achieve expected result, use below option of z-index

```
a{
  position:relative;
  z-index:9999
}
```

https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/gzrzgO

Comment: usually ideal to have manageable `z-index` values, `z-index: 1` would probably work fine

Comment: yes @Yoda, just to make it stays on top of everything,anything works

Answer (score 1):

You can use onclick for the anchor tag:

`<a href="#" onclick="window.location='bar.html'">link</a>`