# Why javascript is triggering multiple functions

Tags: javascript, func

I want to take the count of button clicks along with the count of clicks OUT OF THE BUTTON ON PAGE anywhere. In order to achieve that I generated two functions. 
One inside button element and the other one inside the HTML element. 
My problem is that when the button is clicked, two functions are getting triggered.
And I don't want the Html function to trigger when the button is clicked.
 How can i do that?

```
<html lang="en"  onclick="myPFunction()">
<button class="btn btn-primary"  onclick="myBFunction()"> Click me!</button>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Button onclick inside whole clickable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862228/button-onclick-inside-whole-clickable-div)

Comment: The question you pointed is same. But it is very diffucult to understand that both is the same.  because of the poorly writing. it is not very comprehensible. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add an `event.stopPropagation()` to your `myBFunction()`.  This will prevent your click event from bubbling up to your html element.

check it out:  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_stoppropagation.asp

Comment: thanks @SethLutske. you solved my problem.